# JS href atrribute returns whole url

Tags: javascript, url, href

```
<a id="link" href="file.ext">

getElementById('link').href  //returns whole server url + file.ext
```

Is there any way to read exactly what is in href between the quotes.

I usually remove the server address & path with JS but in my current project the folder structure is so complex that I cannot always predict how much of the url must be removed.

http://jsfiddle.net/Eq8hP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
document.getElementById('link').attributes['href'].value
```

Comment: Actually Alex K.'s answer is more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can;

```
document.getElementById('link').getAttribute("href")
```